# Issue with copying over strings when implementing strrchr in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

For a homework assignment, I have to implement 22 functions in string.h. I'm working on implementing strrchr but have run into some issues when trying to copy the resulting matching string.

Here is my current attempt at implementing it:

```
char *new_strrchr(const char *str, int c) {
    const char *str_copy = str;
    int i, index = -1;
    char *result;
    for(i = 0; *str_copy != '\0'; ++str_copy, ++i){
        if(*str_copy == c) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if(index == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    while(index < strlen(str))
    {
        *result = str[index];
        result++;
        index++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For some reason, `result` has some weird behavior going on. I'll illustrate with an example.

```
char str1[] = "abcHdefHello World";
char search = 'H';
char *result;
result = new_strrchr(str1, search);
printf("Result: %s\n", result);
```

This should print out `Hello World`, since it skips the initial 'H'. However, it instead prints out `HHdefHello World`.

Originally, I thought it had to do with how I'm implementing the actual algorithm to find the last character, but when I did `printf("%c",str[index]);`, in the `while` loop, my output ended up being `Hello World`. So, I can say for certain I was at the right index, and I was outputting the correct characters.

I guess it has something to do with `result` but I don't know what it could be. I even tried adding a null character at the end using `*result = 0` but that ended up just deleting the entire string.

Comment: Don't return a *copy* but just a *pointer*

Comment: The documentation for `strrchr` says _"Returns a pointer to the last occurrence of character in the C string str"_. It says nothing about copying anything, so I'm not sure what the last loop in your function is for(?).

Comment: @Michael you are right, I didn't read it closely enough. Sorry, I made this wayyyy more complicated than it should have been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code: The variable `result` is not initialized and yet you use it.

The value of uninitialized local (non-static) variables is *indeterminate*, and will in reality be seemingly random. That means you don't know where `result` points. Dereferencing and adding to it is what causes the undefined behavior.

I think you need to [read more about the actual `strrchr` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) because it doesn't make a copy, but just returns a pointer to the last matched character in the passed string.

Comment: How would I go about initializing it? When I tried to just do `char result[250]`, the compiler warned me about returning local variables. Is there something that I should be doing? Edit: I'll read more about it now, thank you.

Comment: @Alex The solution is actually much simpler than you think. Hint: Loop *backwards*.